# Sails.js - Multiple Controller/models in one page

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm new to MVC pattern and Sails. From my understanding, it seems like I should create a controller for each model. A controller is like one page.
So, if I want create a page containing product category, product list and user authentication, there are 3 models in my page. How should I structure the controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have create separate controllers for each model. 
Controllers handle the request from the client and return views, JSON, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may be being influenced by how sails documentation explains things due to their blueprints.

Mvc does not require a 1 to 1 of controller to model. Your controller should take care of massing the data and rules needed to show your view or a group of different views. A controller may have a link to a group of your functionality e.g. user management where you handle registrations, login, forgotten credentials etc. This may require a few different models and not just your user model. It may also display a number of different views too.

Sails.js comes with blueprints enabled which means a user model will have create,update,find,findone etc against a user model. Infact sails doesnt need a controller in this instance but you could make one to over ride logic or add additional logic. There is however nothing stopping you calling a user.find method in the user controller as well as a pets.find. Just think of the controller as the conductor telling and calling everything to fire and bringing this information together to push into a view or number of views.

Comment: Thank you munkee. It's very helpful.